# How does radio button stay selected when other activity is initiated using an intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, radio-button

My Main activity has a group radio buttons. When each of them is clicked, it initiates a different activity. All the activities have the same XML but the inputs and the functionality is different. What I mean is the radio group is common for all Activities. For Example: When a first radio button is clicked, it initiates a different activity and the radio box selection disappears. I need the clicked radio button selection to stay on until a different radio button from the group is clicked though it is in a different activity. How do I get this working? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view){
     boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_199os:
            if (checked){

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

            break;
        case R.id.radio_399os:
            if (checked){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Third.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }                 

            break;
        case R.id.radio_2000os:
            if (checked){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fourth.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
                //
            break;
    }         

}
```

Comment: Do you mean, when radio button in second activity is selected, you want the same happened to MainActivity, when resumed?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the following to make checked 
 check for selected

```
radio_2000os.setChecked(true);
```

uncheck for others

```
radio_199os.setChecked(false);
```

your Code would be like this

```
  public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view){
     boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_199os:
            if (checked){

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                 radio_2000os.setChecked(false);
                 radio_399os.setChecked(false);
                 radio_199os.setChecked(true);


            }

            break;
        case R.id.radio_399os:
            if (checked){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Third.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                 radio_2000os.setChecked(false);
                 radio_399os.setChecked(true);
                 radio_199os.setChecked(false);
            }                 

            break;
        case R.id.radio_2000os:
            if (checked){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fourth.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                 radio_2000os.setChecked(true);
                 radio_399os.setChecked(false);
                 radio_199os.setChecked(false);
            }
                //
            break;
    }         

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried the above code but it didn't work. When it initiates a new activity the selection doesn't stay on....

Comment: this will occure becasue when you return from other activity to this this activity start again and loose its state 
you need to do some work Take 3 static boolean and in each case true that one whose RB is selected and in onresume method  you have to condition something according to your scenario hope this will work